# Filter top n values a property in an array of objects based on other property values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array of objects similar to

```
var array = [
{year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 20},
{year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 10},
{year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 5},
{year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 45},
{year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 20},
{year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 17},
{year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 100},
{year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 46},
{year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 30},
{year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 15},
{year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 10},
{year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 5}]
```

I'd like to be able to filter this array by the top n values in count by year and rating. I think slice(0,5) would work, but I'm a javascript noob and can't figure out how to iterate over the array based on the year and rating.

I would expect the result for the top 2 to be:

```
[
    {year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 20},
    {year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 10},
    {year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 45},
    {year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 20},
    {year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 100},
    {year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 46},
    {year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 15},
    {year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 10}
]
```

Comment: Can you share your expected result for the data provided?

Comment: Sure! So, if I wanted to get the objects with the top 2 values for count I'd expect to see:

var new_array = [
{year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 20},
{year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 10},
{year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 45},
{year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 20},
{year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 100},
{year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 46},
{year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 15},
{year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 10}]

Comment: Is the input data always sorted by `year` and `rating`?

Comment: Yes, I was able to sort the array in the appropriate order.

Comment: And does the order of the objects in the output array need to match the order of the objects from the original array? eg: could `{...... count: 10}` come before `{...... count: 15}` in the result?

Comment: Ideally, yes, though I think I could sort the new/filtered array appropriately after the filtering was done.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `year` and `rating` (using `year-rating` keys) by using `.reduce()` and `Map` so that you have an array of objects which indicate the count and the index that each object occurs at:

```
2000-1: [{count: 20, idx: 0}, {count: 10,idx: 1}, {count: 5, idx: 2}, ...],
2000-2: [{count: 45, idx: 4}, ...],
2001-1: [...],
2001-2: [...]
```

once you have a Map of the above structure, you can sort each value array by the count in ascending order, and use `.slice(-n)` to obtain the top (last) `n` elements. Once you have the top elements, you can map each `top` value arrays to their actual object values using the `idx` property. Before you do this though, you can sort by `idx` to retain the relative ordering:

```js
const arr = [ {year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 20}, {year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 10}, {year: 2000, rating: 1, count: 5}, {year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 45}, {year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 20}, {year: 2000, rating: 2, count: 17}, {year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 100}, {year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 46}, {year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 30}, {year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 15}, {year: 2001, rating: 2, count: 10}, {year: 2001, rating: 1, count: 5} ];

const n = 2;
const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((acc, {year, rating, count}, idx) => {
  const key = `${year}-${rating}`;
  const curr = acc.get(key) || []; 
  return acc.set(key, [...curr, {count, idx}])
}, new Map).values(), group => group.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count).slice(-n)).flatMap(
  top => top.sort((a, b) => a.idx - b.idx).map(({idx}) => arr[idx])
);
console.log(res);
```